Replace rows with nearest time using pyspark
I have a dataframe in PySpark:
id    time         replace
3241  2024-01-31   false
4344  2019-09-01   true
5775  2022-02-01   false
5394  2018-06-16   true
7645  2023-03-11   false

I want to find rows where replace == true and replace the time column with the nearest time among rows where replace == false. I want to do this for all rows where replace == true.

What is your current approach? What's your difficulty?

I was thinking of ordering the rows by time
ordered_df = df.orderBy("time")
then adding a monotonically increasing ID to the rows, filtering replace==true and replacing the time with the time of the row with monotonically _increasing_id - 1 problem is that my data is huge so I'm looking for the most efficient method

what is the expected output for the above input? And why that output follows the rules you laid out.

When you say nearest di you mean nearest after that time, or before and after ?

it's sorted by time so nearest row before works fine

You can solve it using a combination of window functions by partitioning by "replace" and ordering by "time":
w = Window.orderBy("time")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("tmp")
df.withColumn("tmp", when(col("replace"), 0).otherwise(1)) \
    .withColumn("tmp", sum("tmp").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("time", when(col("replace"), last(lag("time", -1).over(w)).over(w2)).otherwise(col("time"))) \
    .drop("tmp")

